# Azure powershell runbook don't show any output

Tags: azure, powershell, output, runbook

I have a simple Azure PowerShell runbook script
workflow CheckIdentityColumns
{
    Write-Output "Test Output"
}
[image: Script]

When I am trying to test it I don't see any output.
[image: No Output]

Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your flow is **Powershell runbook** not **Powershell Workflow runbook** .
[image] In Powershell runbook, you don't need to use

```
workflow CheckIdentityColumns{}
```

declaration. This is the main reason why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your scenario and it worked for me. You can view the details below.

This happened to me in different scenario. The answer I got from Microsoft support was that the Runbook in the cache is still the older one, i.e. an empty Runbook in your case. All you need to do is:

1. Publish the Runbook and edit and test again
2. If it still doesn't work then clear the cache and restart your browser

Test Runbook:
[image: Test Runbook]

Output: 
[image: Output of the Execution]

Comment: When I wrote just Write-Output "Test Output"  it worked for me.