# Runbook test pane is not showing Write-Output

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I'm brand new to automation, and pretty new to Powershell as well, so I'm hoping this is a simple fix. :)

I'm trying to get some code to run. And for all I know, it does run, but the test pane doesn't show anything. Based on this thread: [Azure powershell runbook don't show any output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965153/azure-powershell-runbook-dont-show-any-output), I did try republishing the code and clearing my browser cache, but that didn't help in my case, so I'm thinking there's an issue with the code?

Here's my (genericized) code):

```
workflow DB_DailyTasks 
{
    Write-Output "Code starting"

    inlinescript 
    {
        [string] $SqlServerName = "myDb.database.windows.net"
        $Credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "myDatabase-automation"
        # Setup credentials   
        $ServerName = $Using:SqlServerName
        $UserId = $Using:Credential.UserName
        $Password = ($Using:Credential).GetNetworkCredential().Password

        # Execute the udp_myProc procedure

        # Create connection for each individual database
        $DatabaseConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $DatabaseCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

        Write-Output "ConnectionState is: $(DatabaseConnection.State)"

        $DbName = "myDb"

        # Setup connection string for $DbName
        $DatabaseConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$ServerName; Database=$DbName; User ID=$UserId; Password=$Password;"
        $DatabaseConnection.Open();

        Write-Output "ConnectionState is: $(DatabaseConnection.State)"

        # Create command for a specific database $DBName
        $DatabaseCommand.Connection = $DatabaseConnection

        Write-Output "Running udp_myProc procedure"

        $DatabaseCommand.CommandText = "EXECUTE [dbo].[udp_myProc]"
        $NonQueryResult = $DatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        # Close connection to $DbName
        $DatabaseConnection.Close()        
    }
}
```

...and here's what I see in the test pane when I try to test:
[image: Unhelpful test pane]

...which isn't terribly helpful in knowing whether it actually ran.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide! :)

[Edit] The code is definitely not running. The stored procedure inserts an entry into a history table, and there's no record of it running either for the tests or for when I ran the published output.

Interesting note, though - when I ran the published output, there were no errors and no warnings, but it did say, "This job does not have any output" in the Output tab.

[Edit #2]: It doesn't write anything on my local computer either??

[Edit #3]: Replaced Write-Output with Write-Host inside the inlinescript block. No change, either on Azure admin console or on my local computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you created a **PowerShell** runbook, not a **PowerShell Workflow** runbook. If this is correct, then your runbook code *declares* a workflow called DB_DailyTasks, but never *invokes* it. For example, you could *declare* a function, but would not expect it to be automatically *invoked* because of that.

Unless you are certain that you need a *workflow*, not a regular PowersShell runbook, I would recommend removing `workflow` and `InlineScript` from your code, and deal with regular PowerShell.

However, if you really need it to be a workflow (not recommended unless you have to use checkpoints and things like `parallel` and `foreach -parallel`), then create a runbook of the "PowerShell Workflow" type: it treats the `workflow` keyword differently, so your code would be correct.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that there was a difference between a workbook runbook and a regular runbook - I just copied and modified code from a blog. :) With your pointer, I removed the workbook definition and the inline-script block, and that enabled it to... show a bunch of errors. :D But that was an improvement... a bit of troubleshooting later, and it works now (stored procedure is running and everything). Thanks again!